# How to get a wav file from a POST body to upload it using Node JS/Express

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am creating a node js app who's purpose is, in part, receiving a POST request and then parsing the body for 2 fields: id and a .wav file.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to parse the req body correctly. I believe the request should be multipart/form-data (which is why I'm using multer and not bodyParser), but I keep getting undefined when I try the log(body.req.file) and the res shows the 500 internal server error I send in the app.post function.

Here is the server code...

Multer part :

```
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
var uploadFields = upload.fields([{name: 'id'}, {name: 'file'}])

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, 'temp/')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
        fileBody = file
        keyName = `${req.body.id}.` + getExtension(file)
        var objectParams = {Bucket: myBucket, Key: keyName, Body: fileBody}
        s3.putObject(objectParams).promise().then(function(res){console.log('wewlad')}).catch(function(err){console.log(err)})
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + getExtension(file))
    }
})
```

Express part:

```
app.post('/', uploadFields, function(req, res){
    console.log('POST to / recieved!')
    console.log(req.body.id)
    console.log(req.body.file)  

    fileBody = req.files
    keyName = req.body.id + '.wav'
    var params = {Bucket: myBucket, Key: keyName, Body: fileBody}
    var putObjectPromise = s3.putObject(params).promise()
    putObjectPromise.then(function(res){
        console.log(res)

    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err)
    })
})
```

a getExtension function I made (not sure if this is needed)...

```
function getExtension(file) {
    var res = ''
    //some of these are being used for testing
    if (file.mimetype === 'audio/wav') res = '.wav'
    else if (file.mimetype === 'audio/basic') res = '.ul'
    else if (file.mimetype === 'multipart/form-data') res = '.wav'
    else if (file.mimetype === 'application/octet-stream') res = '.ul'
    else console.log(`ERROR: ${file.mimetype} is not supported by this application!`)
    return res
}
```

Side-note: I am using post-man to send the id and file as form-data

Any help is greatly appreciated! Also, if there's anything I left out let me know!

EDIT:
Tried again with new info, this is my attempt:

```
 var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' }) //what do I put here to not store file
 ...
 ...
 app.post('/', upload.single('file'), function(req, res, next){
    console.log('POST to / received!')
    console.log(req.body.id)
    console.log(req.file)

    var fileBody = req.file //and what do I put here to get access to the file
    var keyName = `audio-${req.body.id}.${getExtension(req.file)}`
    var params = { Bucket: myBucket, Key: keyName, Body: fileBody }
    var putObjectPromise = s3.putObject(params).promise()

    putObjectPromise.then(function(res){
        console.log(res)
        res.sendStatus(204);
    }).catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
        next(err)
    })
});
```

it results in an "InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Body to be a string, buffer, stream, blob, or typed array object" that I is coming from S3 validating the params for the putObject call

Solution for anyone that passes by in the future:

```
 var upload = multer()


app.post('/', upload.single('file'), function(req, res, next){
    //for debugging purposes
    console.log('POST to / received!')
    console.log(req.body.id)
    console.log(req.file)

    //set the parameters for uploading the files to s3
    var fileBody = req.file.buffer
    var keyName = `audio_logs/audio-${req.body.id}.${getExtension(req.file)}`
    var params = { Bucket: myBucket, Key: keyName, Body: fileBody }

    //upload the audio file and then state when done. Log any errors.
    var putObjectPromise = s3.putObject(params).promise()
    putObjectPromise.then(function(res){
        console.log('Uploaded -> ' + res)        
    }).catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
        next(err)
    })
});
```

Comment: It looks like you may want to use `req.files` instead of `req.body.file` with [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#usage).

Comment: As a sidenote, it appears your "filename" function is trying to upload to S3 as well as the actual express post function as well, which you probably don't want.

Comment: @shortstuffsushi oh, yea, you're right. Now I'm getting an error: "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Comment: At what point are you getting that issue? You should be able to see the line it's failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @shortstuffsushi pointed out, since you're using `multer.fields`, file metadata is parsed into `req.files`.

However, that object is not the actual file body.
It's a key->value map where each key is one of the fields you defined in `multer.fields` and each value is an *array of file objects*.

So if I'm reading your code correctly, you'll have to access your file as `req.files['file'][0]`.

Additionally, since you configured multer to use DiskStorage, that file object won't contain the actual file body. Instead, it will have a `path` property which points to the file on your file system.

So in order to upload it to S3, you first have to read it from disk into a buffer or stream (depending on what the upload library can use) and then use that to actually upload the file's data.

---

If you are only uploading a single file per request, you should consider using `multer.single` instead of `multer.fields`. I suppose the `id` field is a number or string, so specifying that in `multer.fields` only makes it try to parse nonsense into a file.

And with `multer.single` the file metadata will be parsed into `req.file` (no 's'), so you don't need the extra "map into array" access.

So a full example would look like this:

```
const readFile = require('util').promisify(require('fs').readFile)

app.post('/', upload.single('file'), function(req, res, next){
    console.log('POST to / received!')
    console.log(req.body.id)
    console.log(req.file)  

    readFile(req.file.path)
      .then(body => {
        const params = { Bucket: myBucket, Key: req.body.id + '.wav', Body: body }
        return s3.putObject(params).promise();
      })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result)
        res.sendStatus(204);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        next(err);
      });
});
```

And just as @shortstuffsushi mentioned, the `filename` config for multer should not upload the file as well.

Comment: Better, more thorough answer. Fwiw, I believe the S3 library may allow you to provide a file path as well (and do the stream stuff internally).

Comment: The `Key` parameter is the file path on S3, at least for the S3 client from the official aws-sdk. And that library can except a Buffer, String or Stream for `Body`.

Comment: @LucasS. I don't necessarily need it to save to disk, I was just experimenting with multer. How would you change it so that instead of needing to use readFile I could just upload the file from req.file ?

Comment: Update: I've gotten it to work and updated the OP with the solution. Big thanks to @ LucasS. and @shortstuffsushi !

Comment: @OtterJesus Great, glad I could help. One thing to note about buffering full files though, is that it will eat up a lot of RAM if files are big and/or there are a lot of requests at the same time.

While quickly searching through npm I found [multer-s3-acl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3-acl), which uses Streams and therefore doesn't have aforementioned limitations.
Maybe you want to give that a try as well.

Answer (score 1):

Converting to an answer for your first problem, multer uses the `files` property on the request, not `body.file`. Check out [their docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#usage) for more.